# Authenticating client certificate GnuTLS

Tags: ssl, encryption, cryptography, certificate, gnutls

So, for an assignment I need to use GnuTLS and to start of, I followed the client and server examples in the documentation (http://www.gnutls.org/manual/gnutls.html) (client and server examples with X.509). Everything works fine till there.

However, I would like the server to authenticate the client (which, in the examples, does not by default). A little research has lead me to changing the flag GNUTLS_CERT in:

`gnutls_certificate_server_set_request (mSession, GNUTLS_CERT_REQUEST);`

I understand that this returns an error if the client does not provide a certificate that matches the server's trusted CA. However, is this enough to authenticate the client, or should there be more steps for authentication?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a good question. It does seem to imply TLS *client authentication*, but for a security topic the documentation of the API is too sparse (just sending the client cert. is of course not enough, but as far as I know, that only happens *as part of* client authentication). Just try it and monitor the SSL connection or get it working and then remove the private key of the client - it should fail when that happens.